# Wrong image ratio in Safari browser

Tags: html, css

On the iPhone or also on a Mac with Safari Browser some images get the wrong ratio if the window size is smaller than the image width. In other browsers (on windows) it works fine and the ratio is changing fine.

Because I have only an iPhone, could somebody check and find out the issue with a Mac?

For example: The image with the groom at the first look topic:
https://christianwagnerfilms.com/welcomeguide/index.html

Thanks,
Christian

Comment: Please add your code to the question, together with a decent description of the error and the things you've tried.

Comment: Description I wrote already... the image ratio isn't correct but only on Safari browsers with a window size small than 600 pixel.

Comment: You still need to add your code. We can't help you without some code to look at.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem in Chrome under Windows (not in Mozilla though), so it's not iPhone or Safari specific. @rblarsen The problem is identified already, so some people are able to help with only a link to go on.

Answer (score 1):

This rule is causing the image to stretch:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1030px) {
    .img-right {
        display: flex; /* this declaration */
    }
}
```